# Wrapper question when containing floating divs

Tags: css, html, wrapper

I would like to create a, browser centered, bordered, wrapper that autoexpands in height around various divs. When using floats to keep the divs in-line, the wrapper just stops after the first div. Be kind, this may or may not be right way to do this but that's why I'm here.

Here is a simple example.

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
#wrapper {
height: 100%;
width: 800px;
border: 1px solid #000;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
#header {
height: 100px;
width: 800px;
}
#column1 {
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
float: left;
}
#column2 {
height: 400px;
width: 300px;
float: left;
}
#navbox {
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 400px;
}
-->
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">test header</div>
<div id="navbox">test navbox</div>
<div id="column1">test column1</div>
<div id="column2">test column2</div>

</div><!--Close_wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 23):

The answer to questions that contain `float` and `wrap` in one sentence is usually

```
overflow: auto
```

:)

If you want your wrapper to auto-expand in height, that *should* do it.

Comment: By far the most elegant solution I found to the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer and with a pithy rule of thumb to boot!  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can add something like <br style="clear:both" /> as the last element in your wrapper to force it to wrap around your elements that are outside the content stream.

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">test header</div>
<div id="navbox">test navbox</div>
<div id="column1">test column1</div>
<div id="column2">test column2</div>

<br style="clear:both" />

</div><!--Close_wrapper-->
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an element with `clear:both` after the `div`s.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ageto)

Answer (score 3):

I would use the :after psuedo class like below. It seems a bit more obvious what is supposed to happen and a bit less like browser weirdness. I'm sure not that overflow solution is *officially* supposed to work.

```
#wrapper:after {
    clear:both;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
}
```